# Freeing memory tied to errors in IPython Notebook

Tags: memory, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I sometimes work with very large data sets in IPython Notebooks. Sometimes a single pandas DataFrame will take up 1+GB of memory, so I can't afford to keep many copies around.

What I've found is that if I try to perform an operation on such a matrix, and an error is raised, I don't get the memory back - some intermittent variable is still being tracked somewhere. The problem is, I don't know where and can't free it up!

For example, the image below shows the memory consumption after repeated attempts to execute the cell (each step in the graph corresponds to an attempt to execute the cell). Each time a new block of memory is consumed that is never released.

[image: Memory usage while executing a cell that raises an error]

Does anyone know where this memory is going and how to free it up? Alternatively, if this is a bug (i.e. memory leak or similar), how do you show that? I didn't want to report this as a bug if it is actually the side effect of code performing as designed (e.g. IPython is caching things and I'm just abusing the caching system).

Thank you!

Comment: I have a similar problem with Jupyter consuming way too much RAM. I did not yet identify the exact source of the problem, but Jupyter stays up on the server for days and notebooks are frequently opened and closed. I came across this https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8267 issue, and thought it might be somehow interconnected. The proposed solution (update `jsonschema`) did not help me, but might work for you

Comment: Thank you @Pocin for the link. Another issue has been raised on the jupyter project: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/642. Perhaps you can add a comment there with your experience to help the devs get more information on the matter.

Comment: What platform are you on and what are you using to monitor memory? Trying to track down related issues..

Comment: Hi dartdog - I had forgotten to close this question. Per suggestion in #642, I updated jsonschema and have not had any more problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per discussion on github concerning [issue 642](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/642), there is a known memory leak in jsonschema 2.4. After updating to jsonschema 2.5.1, I have no longer had this problem.

So, if you're using an older framework and seeing this issue, you will need to upgrade at least jsonschema.